# how can i get the same effect comes by "ctrl + k" in stackoverflow question, in my html code?

Tags: html, content-management-system, wordpress

see by writting some code here we select that code & press ctrl + K and that code now prints in something different format.

printf("this is code");

see now i copy uper sentences code & paste it below in ctrl+ k mode

```
printf("this is code");
```

okey so now i want to know how can i get same effect in my wordpress-blog's  post?

any plugin or any technique or any html tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a WP plugin which can handle source code syntax highlighting. Here are some examples which may work for you:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/screenshots/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-syntax-highlighter/screenshots/

Comment: first one seems good but not best...if i dont find any other better way then i will use 1st one plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a code highlighter. For WordPress, Geshi-backed highlighters are pretty common. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/geshi

Answer (score 0):

You'll be looking for the <pre> tag.

Comment: using pre tag i dont get same effect which stackoverflow give us

Comment: The pre tag will use a monospaced font by default, but it won't give you any other styles or syntax highlighting.

Comment: What effect are you trying to mimic? The syntax highlighting?

Comment: Mr.32: I want a million dollars. We need to see effort to learn and accept hints - not a crying baby. At least __try__ something and come back later.